# I've been trying to get a value from an HTML input box posted into an Oracle Thin database through JSP for hours with no luck

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, netbeans, glassfish-4

I'm using Netbeans and the Oracle-thin connection has been tested and verified multiple times.   I'm in dire straits right now because I'm all out of ideas.   I'm using Glassfish 4.1 for this.

Here's my code:
**index.html**

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<!--Date: Spring 2016-->
  <title>Forgot Password</title>
 <center>
 <head>
<!--Calling the external style sheet-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/LoginStyleSheet.css" type="text/css" />
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="login">
      <h1>Forgot Password</h1>
      <form method="post" action="newjsp.jsp">
        <p><input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email"></p>
        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Forgot     Password"></p>
        <p><a href="">Back to Login</a></p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>

 </center>
 </html>
```

This is **newjsp.jsp**

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
         <title>JSP Page</title>
     </head>
     <body>
         <h1>Hello World!</h1>
         <%
 String email = request.getParameter("email");
 //add null checks and all
 //Similarly get all datamobileno etc
 //then call your submitData() method
 testServlet myTest = new testServlet();
 myTest.submitData(email);
 %>
     </body>
 </html>
```

This is **testServlet.java**

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
//import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/testServlet"})
public class testServlet extends HttpServlet {

   public void submitData(String email) throws SQLException,         ClassNotFoundException  {  


            Connection con = null;  

            try {  
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");  
            }  
            catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {  
                System.out.println("Error: unable to load driver class!");  
                System.exit(1);  
            }  

            con =     DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","javauser","ja    vapass");  
            Statement statement = con.createStatement();  

           String command = "INSERT INTO JAVAUSER.test (TESTER) VALUES ('" +     email + "');";  
           statement.executeUpdate(command);  

           con.close();  
       }  

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,     HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample     code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet testServlet</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet testServlet at " +     request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods.     Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse     response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse     response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

I based this off the most applicable example I could find online after about 5 hours of trying to figure this out.   I keep getting this error, and I have no idea why.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error


type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from     fulfilling this request.

exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for     JSP

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /newjsp.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class testServlet
  location: class org.apache.jsp.newjsp_jsp

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /newjsp.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class testServlet
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import `testServlet` to be recognized on compiling the JSP page.

Include this at the top of your JSP, changing package name

```
<%@ page import="mypackagename.testServlet" %>
```

EDT:

Are you sure that your DB password includes so much blanks?

```
 DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE",
                             "javauser","ja    vapass");
```

Comment: That leads to "This page cannot be displayed."  once I hit the submit button.   Here's a picture of what everything looks like. [link](http://i.imgur.com/CEwomhe.png)   If it means anything, I had to change the port for GlassFish to 9999 for it to not interfere with Oracle.

Comment: Check the stacktrace in the server log for more info.

Comment: I checked it but the only thing I could decipher that could maybe help is "visiting unvisited references.'

Comment: Probably there is another different error in your method 'submitData'. Try to test it in a POJO and let me know what happens.

Comment: Edited my answer with another thing to look up.

Answer (score 0):

> I based this off the most applicable example I could find online after about 5 hours of trying to figure this out

Whereever you found that most "applicable example": Ditch it and start over. I've never seen anybody instantiate a servlet within a JSP to delegate request handling. You'd submit your request to a servlet, which would - after processing the request - forward to a JSP for display purposes. But you'd never instantiate a servlet on your own - that's the container's (tomcat's) duty.

As of the answer to your question

```
exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP
```

and

```
PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /newjsp.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class testServlet
  location: class org.apache.jsp.newjsp_jsp
```

should give it away. For the reasons stated above, I'd urge you to *not* fix *this* issue though but rather start over with a proper servlet that handles this request. As I can't imagine who in their right mind publishes a tutorial that makes you instantiate a servlet, I'd say *any* tutorial that you find anywhere should do the trick and teach you proper servlet development. Just not the one that you've used here.

It's always the servlet that sees the request first - JSP is a view layer that the servlet delegates to after it's been done processing the request.

This is not to be understood rude or letting you down - it's just a very firm statement that the code that you posted is unfixable IMHO - it needs a complete rewrite.